# How to update sub document whose parent key has space in?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54b60ee28115386561cda04b"),
    "a b" : "{c:d}",
}
```

I need to update 'a b'.c to value 'e'. Tried query below

```
db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("54b60ee28115386561cda04b")}, {$set:{'a b.c':'e'}});
```

but get error:

```
LEFT_SUBFIELD only supports Object: a b not: 2
```

Any advice, please?

Comment: Neil. I understand it's not a good idea, but this property comes from external source, which I have no control over the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having a space in a key name ( except it looks bad and not a good practice ). So you can modify a correctly formed document with no problem.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54b60ee28115386561cda04b"),
    "a b" : { "c": "d" }
}
```

And update:

```js
db.test.update(
   { "_id": ObjectId("54b60ee28115386561cda04b") }, 
   { "$set": { "a b.c": "e" } }
);
```

But your problem here is that the content of "a b" is a string. So there is no "c" sub-property to access.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54b60ee28115386561cda04b"),
    "a b" : "{c:d}",
}
```

Correct the document to contain a nested object:

```js
db.test.update(
   { "_id": ObjectId("54b60ee28115386561cda04b") }, 
   { "$set": { "a b": { "c": "e" } } }
);
```

Future updates will work properly then

Comment: Does this mean 'a b' will lose all other sub properties after this query if there is any?

Comment: @Ming There are no subproperties because "It's a string". If you have something that looks like `"a b": "{c:d,e:f}"` then that value is a "string" and not an object and you probably have some bad code that is causing this. I'm telling you the mistake and how to correct it.

Comment: Thanks, Neil. Get it.